# Disable the swipe on mobile for the tab section on enfold

Tags: wordpress, mobile, tabs, accordion, swipe

How to disable the swipe on mobile for the tab section on enfold? I had an issue on enfold template builder. I wanted to put 2 tab sections. Inside each, I wanted to have the accordion slider. However, the swiping on mobile started to interfere with each other, on PC it works perfectly. Should I disable the tab swipe on mobile or is there another solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are looking for help for a specific third-party plugin, you would be better to contact the plugin developer's support.